# 2014 chevy equinox won't start

Tags: chevrolet, starter, relay, ignition-switch, equinox

Bypassed the starter relay and the starter turns...tried new starter relay, didn't help. Starter fuse good. Tried starting in both park and neutral, doesn't start in either. Why isn't the starter relay getting it's coil voltage? And how can I troubleshoot it? Where's a good place to get the wiring diagram free/cheap?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is there anything that indicates that the immobilizer is still active?  Have you tried the spare keys?

Comment: Presuming the security indicator isn't ON during starting (and  pointing to GMs immobilizer system), tried measuring for 12v on the small wire on the starter when someone turns the ignition switch to START? It's safer if you can disconnect the 'S' wire from the starter before measuring for voltage.

Comment: No spare keys available. Would reprogramming the old one help? How do I test the immobilizer?

Comment: Unless you're absolutely sure the factory GM chipped key transponder and immobilizer system is preventing startup, your presumptions may be incorrect. GM uses at least one indicator to inform you whether or not theft deterrent is On, Off, blinking or flashing. GM online provides electronic owners manuals. Either your factory immobilizer is active (possibly flashing) and preventing engine running or this problem lies with the electronic starting circuit.

Comment: Got a new key and it worked! Apparently the old key's programming was messed up. Thanks for all your help!